# Active directory setting for auto-logon of a computer; Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server, auto-login

I remember there was a setting in Windows Server 2003 that made a user account on the domain auto-logon when the computer booted up. It was just one setting on the server, and not a registry edit on the local computer. Does anybody know what it was called and where to find it?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310584, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737, http://www.petri.co.il/configuring_autologon.htm

Answer (score 0):

The [source](http://www.techzonez.com/forums/showthread.php/4482-Windows-2003-Automatic-Login) is poorly formatted, but is legible.  Here is a direct copy:

To enable automatic Logon, you must first create AutoAdminLogon REG_Z value.
Open regedt32 and goto the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon registry subkey.
From the dit menu, select Add Value.Enter
[I]AutoAdminLogon

in the Value Name field. Select REG_SZ for the data type.Double click and Enter 1 in the string field nad click OK.
Next, add your logon information to the registry.
For the DefaultDomainName value, enter your domain name.
For the DefaultUserName value, enter your logon username.
For the DefaultPassword value, enter your logon password.
If the DefaultPassword value doesn't exist, select AddValue from the edit menu. 
In the Value Name field. enter Select REG_SZ for the data type.
Finally enter your password in the field string and click OK.
If you don't enter your password in the String field, Win Server 2003 changes the AutoAdminLogon registry value from 1 (true) to 0 (false), thus disabling the AutoAdminLogon feature.
So in otherways make sure you enter your password.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to leave a plain-text password in your reg use [Sysinternals Autologon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905).
It's more secure and easier to use.